# CsvHelper ignore not working

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I am using `CsvHelper` to generate a csv file based on a `List`, but I would like to avoid writing one of the values. As per the [documentation](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), I used a `CsvClassMap` to specify the field that I want to ignore. However, the value is still being written to the file.

Here is my class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `CsvClassMap`:

```
public sealed class PersonClassMap : CsvClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(0).Name("Id");
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Index(1).Name("First Name");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Index(2).Name("Last Name");

        Map(m => m.MiddleName).Ignore();
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I am using to generate the output:

```
var persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Id = 1, FirstName = "Randall", MiddleName = "Michael", LastName = "Perry"},
    new Person {Id = 2, FirstName = "Marigold", MiddleName = "Joanne", LastName = "Mercibar"},
    new Person {Id = 3, FirstName = "Sven", MiddleName = "Ergenfein", LastName = "Olafsson"}
};

using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textWriter))
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(persons);
    textWriter.Flush();
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
Id,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName
1,Randall,Michael,Perry
2,Marigold,Joanne,Mercibar
3,Sven,Ergenfein,Olafsson
```

How can I get it to stop writing the `MiddleName`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The class map must be [registered](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#configuration-register-class-map) at runtime in order for `CsvHelper` to know to use it:

```
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textWriter))
{
    csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonClassMap>();
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(persons);
    textWriter.Flush();
}
```

Also note that, in the current version, you [don't need to explicitly ignore fields](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping-ignore) in the class map (although this will change in the future):

> **Ignore**
>
> Currently this is not used. Mapping will only map properties that you specify. In the future there will be an option to auto map within a class map, and any mappings explicitly stated will override the auto mapped ones. When this happens, ignore will be used to ignore a property that was auto mapped.

With that in mind, you could also simplify your class map like so:

```
public sealed class PersonClassMap : CsvClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(0).Name("Id");
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Index(1).Name("First Name");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Index(2).Name("Last Name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. I learned something useful here. Is something wrong with the response?

Comment: I guess it's because he answered his own question immediately after posting it?

Comment: "It is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged": http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Some releases back, `CsvClassMap<T>` was renamed to `ClassMap<T>`

Answer (score 19):

You can use this label : `[Ignore]`

For example:

```
//Ignored value
[Ignore]
double value0 = 0;

//Serializable value
[Name("value 1")]
double value1 = 0;
```

Comment: Much easier and simpler than the answer of Ryan Kohn.

Comment: Must add using statement for CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;